# Camunda run 7.15 and jmx monitor

Tags: camunda, camunda-plugin

I have Camunda Run 7.15.  It is possible monitor JMX via  java mission controller or something else? I couldn't find any manual or documentation

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Which Camunda RUN distro? Container? zip/tar?
I just tried the zip and it looks like JMX is enabled ootb. I did not have to add the JVM parameters to enabled jmx to the startup script.

After starting Camunda RUN I was able to connect VisualVM (with Graal) to it. https://visualvm.github.io/

[image: VisualVM connected to Camunda RUN locally]

When using a docker container with a Spring Boot application (in this case Camunda RUN), you can enable JMX as described e.g. here:
https://inspeerity.com/blog/how-to-configure-jmx-in-spring-boot-inside-docker

Enable jmx via the spring boot properties:

```
 spring.jmx.enabled=true
```

The jms settings can be configured via the enviornment:

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false \
 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false \
 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=5000 \
 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=5000 \
 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.host=0.0.0.0 \
 -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=0.0.0.0
```

Remember to add a port mapping also for the jmx port when creating the container instance.

Comment: i try camunda 7.15 in docker
ARG VERSION=7.15.0
ARG DISTRO=run
ARG SNAPSHOT=true
ARG EE=false

Comment: I extended my answer to cover the container sceanrio